# Programming DBA Jobs in Stored procs

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs

I am a little new to programming, so any help is appreciated.

Find below the code of my stored proc to delete a table and also create a DBA job which will run on a hourly basis.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure DELETE_My_TABLE(myschema varchar2) as 
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        execute immediate 'delete from '||myschema||'.mytable where clause;';
    END;
        BEGIN
            DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program (
            program_name        => 'DELETE_My_TABLE',
            program_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            program_action      => 'execute DELETE_My_TABLE(myschema)',
            number_of_arguments => 1,
            enabled             => FALSE,
            comments            => 'Program to delete table using a stored procedure.');
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.define_program_argument (
        program_name      => 'DELETE_My_TABLE',
        argument_name     => 'myschema',
        argument_position => 1,
        argument_type     => 'VARCHAR2',
        default_value     => 'myschema');

        DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable (name => 'DELETE_My_TABLE');
    END;

    BEGIN
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
        schedule_name   => 'DELETE_My_TABLE',
        start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0',
        end_date        => NULL,
        comments        => 'Hourly Job to purge SEARCH_TEMP_TABLE');
    END;
END;
/
```

Issues:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
ORA-06512: at "MYSCHEMA.DELETE_My_TABLE", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Will the logic (and syntax)  work?

Comment: What are you trying to acheive with the nested BEGIN ... END blocks?

Comment: This doesn't look right. Your procedure first deletes from the table (fine), but then it creates an hourly schedule to call the same procedure again. When the scheduler calls it, it does the same thing, adding another hourly schedule to call the same procedure again. After a few days you'll have dozens of schedules jobs, I think...

Answer (score 2):

One issue I can see is that you need to take the semi-colon out of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE string:

```
execute immediate 'delete from '||myschema||'.mytable where clause';
                                                                 ^^
                                                         Removed from here
```

thought I suspect this won't solve your immediate problem, which looks like it's your BEGIN ...END blocks.

Answer (score 2):

For the Oracle Scheduler you normally create a program, once. Next you create a job that has the program as action. You can give that job a schedule like you specified in your code but you have to choose. Either you create a schedule and have the job use it, or you give the job it's own repeat interval.

I happen to know about a book ( [Mastering Oracle Scheduler](http://www.packtpub.com/mastering-oracle-scheduler-in-oracle-11g-databases/book) ) that I wrote that could be very helpful.

Comment: Executing this procedure is a 1 time setup.

Comment: Sri,there are quite a few problems in the code. Given the fact that this is not what you are used to do, work in smaller steps. First the part that does the delete, if that works, go to the Scheduler code. Also decide where you want to have arguments and how to use them. For the Create_program part: the program_action is just the procedure name, no arguments, no execute. You also forgot to create the job that should execute the program you defined, based on the schedule that you defined. Ronald.

Comment: I have to agree with @ik_zelf, and even suggest taking another step backwards - Define your needs precisely before writing any code.
What are you hoping to achieve? If all you need is a job that deletes the contents of the table the execute immediate part is not needed at all, and unnecessarily complicates the task.